# RecursionError in Python Matrix Plotting

Tags: python, matrix

I am working on some Optical multilayer problems using Python.

I encountered this error while I was trying to solve the problem and since I am a beginner, it is too hard for me to debug this problem. Any comments and help are appreciated.

The problem is to find Reflectance and Transmittance of |1|2| ....N.... |1|2| structure.
I have a unit cell of materials 1 and 2. And the total structure is N=5 of the unit cell.

And I calculate total transmittance and reflectance using the Transfer Matrix Method.

I have attached my code below.

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sm
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot

# 111

d1, d2, lam, n1, n2 = symbols('d1, d2, lam, n1, n2', real=True, positive=True)

d1 = 100e-9
d2 = 120e-9

n1 = 1.7
n2 = 1.4

N = 5

r12, t12 = (n1 - n2) / (n1 + n2), (2 * n1) / (n1 + n2)
r21, t21 = (n2 - n1) / (n2 + n1), (2 * n2) / (n2 + n1)

psi1 = 2 * np.pi * n1 * d1 / (lam * 1e-9)
psi2 = 2 * np.pi * n2 * d2 / (lam * 1e-9)

# Transfer Matrix at the 1st Border (without 1/t12)
I12 = sm.Matrix([[1, r12], [r12, 1]])
print(f'I12 Matrix:\n{I12}')

# Transfer Matrix in the Slab
L1 = sm.Matrix([[sm.exp(psi1 * -sm.I), 0], [0, sm.exp(psi1 * sm.I)]])
print(f'L1 Matrix:\n{L1}')

# Transfer Matrix at the 2nd Border (without 1/t23)
I21 = sm.Matrix([[1, r21], [r21, 1]])
print(f'I23 Matrix:\n{I21}')

# Transfer Matrix in the Slab
L2 = sm.Matrix([[sm.exp(psi2 * -sm.I), 0], [0, sm.exp(psi2 * sm.I)]])
print(f'L2 Matrix:\n{L2}')

# Total Transfer Matrix: I12 X L2 X I23
coeff = (1 / t12) * (1 / t21)

M1 = I21 * L2
print(f'M1 Matrix:\n{M1}')
M2 = L1 * M1
print(f'M2 Matrix:\n{M2}')
M3 = I12 * M2
print(f'M3 Matrix:\n{M2}')

Munit = coeff * M3
print(f'Munit Matrix:\n{Munit}')

for i in range(N):
    if i == 0:
        Mt = Munit
    else:
        Mt = Mt * Munit
    print(f'{i+1}:{Mt}\n')

t = 1 / Mt[0, 0]
r = Mt[1, 0] / Mt[0, 0]
print(f'r and t:\n{r} {t}')

T = n2 / n1 * abs(t) ** 2
R = abs(r) ** 2
print(f'R and T:\n{R} {T}')

graph = plot(T, (lam, 300, 800), label='T', line_color='b', Show=False)
graph.extend(plot(R, (lam, 300, 800), label='R', line_color='r', Show=False))
graph.xlabel = 'wavelength in nm'
graph.yLabel = 'Transmittance and Reflectance'
graph.legend = True
graph.show()
```

This program shows error message like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "HW5_4.py", line 68, in <module>
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
Process finished with exit code 1
```

And it says that my program encountered an error at the "plot" function.

The previous version of my code that worked perfectly is (similar problem but simpler)

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sm
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.plotting import plot

# 222

d, lam, n1, n2, n3 = symbols('d, lam, n1, n2, n3', real=True, positive=True)

d = 5e-6

n1 = 1
n2 = 2.6
n3 = 1.45

r12, t12 = (n1 - n2) / (n1 + n2), (2 * n1) / (n1 + n2)
r23, t23 = (n2 - n3) / (n2 + n3), (2 * n2) / (n2 + n3)

psi = 2 * np.pi * n2 * d / (lam * 1e-9)

# Transfer Matrix at the 1st Border (without 1/t12)
I12 = sm.Matrix([[1, r12], [r12, 1]])
print(f'I12 Matrix:\n{I12}')

# Transfer Matrix in the Slab
L2 = sm.Matrix([[sm.exp(psi * -sm.I), 0], [0, sm.exp(psi * sm.I)]])
print(f'L2 Matrix:\n{L2}')

# Transfer Matrix at the 2nd Border (without 1/t23)
I23 = sm.Matrix([[1, r23], [r23, 1]])
print(f'I23 Matrix:\n{I23}')

# Total Transfer Matrix: I12 X L2 X I23
coeff = (1 / t12) * (1 / t23)

M1 = L2 * I23
print(f'M1 Matrix:\n{M1}')
M2 = I12 * M1
print(f'M2 Matrix:\n{M2}')

Mt = coeff * M2
print(f'Mt Matrix:\n{Mt}')

t = 1 / Mt[0, 0]
r = Mt[1, 0] / Mt[0, 0]
print(f'r and t:\n{t} {r}')

T = n3 / n1 * abs(t) ** 2
R = abs(r) ** 2

graph = plot(T, (lam, 500, 600), label='T', line_color='b', Show=False)
graph.extend(plot(R, (lam, 500, 600), label='R', line_color='r', Show=False))
graph.xlabel = 'wavelength in nm'
graph.yLabel = 'Transmittance and Reflectance'
graph.legend = True
graph.show()
```

and if anyone knows how to send the Y-axis of the plot to the left and X-axis label to the bottom center, please let me know!

Thank you everybody to help me with this!

Comment: You need to check what's in T, R and lam before plotting, maybe something odd that prevents the plot from completing efficiently.

Comment: @Frederik.L R and T are very long like hundred lines. So, does this happen due to excessive length of calculation?